# How to reduce TextView line spacing

Tags: android, fonts, textview, truetype

I am trying to reduce the line spacing in a TextView by setting a negative 'add' to TextView.setLineSpacing(). It works well except that the bottom line get truncated.

Main layout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:padding="dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

Main activity:  (notice the

```
package com.font_test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/custom_fonts.ttf");
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        tv.setTypeface(typeface);
        tv.setTextSize(60);
        tv.setLineSpacing(-30f, 1f);  // *** -30 to reduce line spacing
        tv.setBackgroundColor(0x280000ff);
        tv.setText("gggkiiikkk" + "\n" + "gikgikgik" + "\n" + "kigkigkig");
    }
}
```

This results in truncation at the bottom of the view (notice the 'g' at the bottom line):

[image: Reducing the line spacing cuts the 'g' at the bottom line]

It seems that the problem is related to incorrect layout measurement. If I set the TextView to

```
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

It does render properly:

[image: Using 'fill_parent' does not truncate the bottom line]

Any idea how to fix it? I don't mind to have ugly workarounds if it helps. I also have access to FontForge and I can modify the font file if needed.

Comment: Does it happen with the built in fonts as well? Or any other custom fonts? It could be that the font is not reporting the correct descent value.

Comment: on the last line also `LineSpacing of -30f` is applying. that is why the last line is not seen properly. so you can `set bottom padding` of 30 in your case...@kcoppock I do not think any thing wrong in `descent  values`

Comment: @kcoppock, I get the same problem with typeface = Typeface.SANS_SERIF;

Comment: @Mohsin, adding android:paddingBottom="60dp" added a margin at the bottom but the font is still truncated. See http://imgur.com/du5xJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If padding doesn't work, margin should do the job. If you still have problem you can always apply the line spacing value to the onMeasure method of the view. You'll have to create a [custom component](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) for that and extend onMeasure.

Comment: Adding android:layout_margin="20dp" or   android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" to the TextView did not help. The last line is still truncated. I think that the margin is added by the parent view, after the TextView determined its desired measure. I will also try you custom component suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Jose. The custom component idea seems to work. See my own answer here. Marking your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: I posted some code for a TextView that fixes this bug. Hope it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13386208/445348

Comment: This not the solution to the question, there actually is a better one below.

Answer (score 10):

littleFluffyKittys answer is good but it didn't work on some devices if the linespacing was set through xml

I calculate the additional height needed by comparing the original height of the font with the height the textview calculates for a line.
If the line height is smaller than the height of the font the diffrence is added one time.

This works down to at least API 10 propably lower (just not tested any lower)

```
public class ReducedLineSpacingTextView extends TextView {

    public ReducedLineSpacingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ReducedLineSpacingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ReducedLineSpacingTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int truncatedHeight = getPaint().getFontMetricsInt(null) - getLineHeight();
        if (truncatedHeight > 0) {
            setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight() + truncatedHeight);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the best solution on here hands down.

Comment: what if I need to reduce the line spacing programmatically i.e. where does `setLineSpacing(float, float)` fits into in your solution?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this same problem but when I was trying to use a spacing multiplier less than 1.

I created a subclass of `TextView` that fixes the truncation of the last line automatically and doesn't require you set a known/fixed spacing at the bottom.

Just use this class and you can use it normally, you don't need to apply any additional spacing or fixes.

```
public class ReducedLineSpacingTextView extends TextView {

    private boolean mNegativeLineSpacing = false;

    public ReducedLineSpacingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ReducedLineSpacingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ReducedLineSpacingTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (mNegativeLineSpacing) { // If you are only supporting Api Level 16 and up, you could use the getLineSpacingExtra() and getLineSpacingMultiplier() methods here to check for a less than 1 spacing instead.
            Layout layout = getLayout();
            int truncatedHeight = layout.getLineDescent(layout.getLineCount()-1);
            setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight() + truncatedHeight);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setLineSpacing(float add, float mult) {
        mNegativeLineSpacing = add < 0 || mult < 1;
        super.setLineSpacing(add, mult);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice!
That'll make the job but it's never a good idea to put constants values wherever we have variables. You can use the lineSpacing values to add them to the onMeasure method in a dinamyc way.
Note that this values are always available through "getLineSpacingExtra()" and "getLineSpacingMultiplier()". Or even easier you can get the value of both summed up: "getLineHeight()".

Although it feels for me that this value should be included in the onMeasure method, you can always measure the exact height you need and then make a simple check:

```
final int measuredHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
if (measuredHeight < neededHeight) {
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth, neededHeight);   
}
```

One last thing, you don't need to pass the context along in a separated attribute. If you have a look to your constructors, the context is already there. If you needed along the code of your component you can just use "getContext()".

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to reduce line spacing in text view
                **

> android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.8"

**

Answer (score 0):

Just add paddingBottom to declaration of your TextView xml, pick a value which produces a good result. And consequently set values for other paddings (top, let and right).  This should fix your problem

Comment: Adding android:paddingBottom="60dp" to the TextView added padding but bottom line font is still truncated. See http://imgur.com/du5xJ

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did based on Jose's answer here and it seems to work. I am not very familiar with the intricate of the layout mechanism. Is this code safe? Any problem with it?

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.font_test.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Added custom TextView that extends the vertical height by N pixels:

```
package com.font_test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        // TODO: provide an API to set extra bottom pixels (50 in this example)
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight() + 50);       
    }
}
```

Result text view rendering without truncation at the bottom:

[image]

Comment: does this really work for you ? for me it acts the same as bottom padding - adds space to textview but last line is still clipped